# For HashMap, should I override hashCode for key or value?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

Does `HashMap` use the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of the key or value to store its entries, i.e., which is the class whose `hashCode` and `equals` methods we need to override? Should it be the key's class (`K`), or the value's class (`V`)?

Comment: You need to override the hashCode for the key, because the map uses the key's hashcodes to store each entry.

Comment: From your question, it seems that you would benefit from reviewing how a key-value data structure (called a `Map` in Java and "dictionary" in some languages) works in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is essentially irrelevant to the Map itself: it's only the key which is considered by the `HashMap` when it is deciding where to put the key/value pair within its internal data structure.

However, you might want to override it for the value too, e.g. if you need to do `map.values().contains(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your key class needs appropriate overrides for hashCode and equals.

The hash code of the key determines which hash bucket an object should be placed in.

The equals method of the key allows you to distinguish between keys which happen to hash to the same bucket.